# How to delete a file from the opening dialogue of LibreOffice?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, filemanager

One handy thing on Windows was, that I could delete files from the opening dialogue of Openoffice **via keyboard delete key**. LibreOffice on Ubuntu does unfortunately seem to lack this functionality and I'm not sure if OpenOffice would have it under Ubuntu as well. Is there a workaround?

[image: file open dialogue]

Comment: Umm delete it with files? I just searched for it and there doesn't seem to be an extension for it, so I would say that you can't do it from that window.

Comment: @Tim Yes in the opening dialog. I have Tons of files and some are really old. It was convenient, as I didn't have to go circles if I spot something I didn't use anymore.

Comment: Voting to close. 'something' is not clear enough. a screenshot would be helpful as a detailed description of how this happens in windows.

Comment: @don.joey info added.

Comment: Ok now I understand! Thanks. I do not think that this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it is possible, sorry. The only alternative is to open it, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to see where it is saved, then browse to it in Files.

Although, [this answer](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7405/how-do-i-delete-actually-opened-text-file-using-only-libreoffice-options-or-another-simple-way/?answer=7413#post-id-7413) may help. It explains how to make a macro on Libre Office.